# Using MYSQL FULL TEXT to search a term with similar values

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If i am search a term 'will come', then the result will show all the entries similar with the search term.
For example:

```
Search Term: will come
Records: 
1. It will come.
2. tomorrow rain will come.
3. it should come
4. come on
5. tomorrow bus will come.
Result: 1, 2, 5
```

I will try with the query `SELECT * FROM user WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+will +come' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` but i get all the entries(1,2,3,4,5) as result.

Comment: Wildcards are only allowed for suffixes, not prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to put into a comment.  The "wildcard" operator is only used for suffixes.  This is well described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> - *
>
> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
>   the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words
>   match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.

There is not an easy way to do what you want in MySQL, because it does not support synonym lists.  Nor does it provide easy access to the dictionary created by the full text search.